# Question about substitutions in the double integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln xy}{1-xy} dx\, dy = 2\zeta(3)$

Tags: integration, substitution

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln xy}{1-xy} dx\, dy = 2\zeta(3) \tag{1}
\end{align}
Since,

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-az} dz = \frac{-\ln (1-a)}{a}
\end{align}
and putting $a = 1-xy$, $(1)$ becomes:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-z(1-xy)} dx\, dy\, dz = 2\zeta(3) \tag{2}
\end{align}
with $t = 1-z(1-xy) \implies dt = -(1-xy) \, dz$. When $z=0$, $t=1$ and when $z=1$, $t=xy.$ Making these substitutions in $(2)$:

\begin{align}
-\int_1^{xy}\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t(1-xy)} dx\, dy\, dt \tag{3}
\end{align}

Is $(3)$ still equal to $2\zeta(3)$? I think $(3)$ will be a function of $x$ and $y$, but after making these substitutions the integral should stay the same.

Comment: I am pretty sure, your outer integral should actually be the inner integral, i.e., you should have $$ - \int_0^1\int_0^1 \int_1^{xy} \frac{1}{t(1-xy)}\,\mathrm{d} x \,\mathrm{d} y\,\mathrm{d} t$$ instead.

Comment: If $dz$ belongs to the outer most integral, why we change the limits of the innner most integral?

Comment: First of all, I made a mistake, in my integral you should have $\mathrm{d} t\,\mathrm{d} x\,\mathrm{d} y$. Second of all, you can bring change the order of integration (Fubini's theorem) and third of all, if you want to have $z$ as the outer one. You should have $z$ from $0$ to $1$. Then the limit for $y$ is a function of $z$ and the limit for $x$ is a function of $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 1):

By geometric series, your integral equals
$$-\int^1_0\int^1_0(\ln x+\ln y)\sum^\infty_{k=0}(xy)^kdydx$$

Due to the symmetry in $x$ and $y$, this equals
$$-2\int^1_0\int^1_0(\ln x)\sum^\infty_{k=0}(xy)^kdydx$$

Since the series converges uniformly, we can integrate it termwise to obtain
$$-2\sum^\infty_{k=0}\int^1_0 x^k\ln x\cdot\frac{1}{1+k} dx$$

Since $\int^1_0 x^k\ln xdx=-\frac1{(1+k)^2}$, this simplifies to
$$2\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{(1+k)^3} =2\zeta(3)$$ by definition.

---

> Prove $\int^1_0 x^k\ln xdx=-\frac1{(1+k)^2}$:
>
> By the substitution $t=-(k+1)\ln x$,
> $$-\int_\infty^0 e^{\frac{-kt}{k+1}}\frac{t}{k+1}\cdot\frac{-1}{1+k}e^{\frac{-t}{k+1}}dt=-\frac1{(k+1)^2}\int^\infty_0te^{-t}dt=-\frac1{(k+1)^2}(1!)=\color{red}{-\frac1{(k+1)^2}}$$